# Multiple Select component for Angular with list style

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I need a select component like [image: Multiple select list]

The problem is they don't have it in Material Angular, so I tried using default HTML select inside the component. It works fine until I tried to destroy the view of the HTML select(for example when you redirect to other page), it will freeze the whole page for a couple of seconds(the larger the list the longer it will freeze).

First, anyone know the reason why Angular takes a while to destroy non material angular component? Then does anyone have a solution whether to make the freeze gone or appoint me to select component library that could be use in Angular perfectly? I really need the support of being able to select multiple items with click + shift

Here's my component code:

HTML:

```
<div class="chart">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="row">
            <i *ngIf="multiple" (click)="resetFilter()" class="option material-icons left">refresh</i>
            <h4>Sample Id</h4>
            <span class="option right"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <select *ngIf="!showSampleCSV" [multiple]="multiple" [size]="100" class="samples-list" [(ngModel)]="selectedSamples" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let sampleID of sampleIDs" [value]="sampleID">{{sampleID}}</option>
      </select>
      <app-samples-text *ngIf="showSampleCSV" [samples]="selectedSamples" [multiple]="multiple" (filterSamples)="filterCSV($event)"></app-samples-text>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-samples-list',
  templateUrl: './samples-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./samples-list.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SamplesListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() sampleIDs : string[] = [];
  @Input() showSampleCSV : boolean;
  @Input() selectedSamples : string[];
  @Output() onSelectSamples = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
  @Output() onUpdateSamples = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
  @Input() multiple: boolean = true;
  size = this.sampleIDs.length;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  resetFilter() {
    this.onSelectSamples.emit(this.sampleIDs);
  }

  onSelect(samples){
    this.onSelectSamples.emit(samples);
  }

  filterCSV(samples){
    this.onUpdateSamples.emit(samples.map(sample => sample.trim()));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

}
```

Problem illustration on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qojyqc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Can we please see your component code (HTML & TS)?

Comment: There is a multiple select option in [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection). And don't know why it freezes. Can you add the codes here or provide a slackblitz url?

Comment: Sure, there's my component code. If I use component from Angular material, it doesn't freeze when I try to destroy the view. However, select component from Angular Material doesn't have click + shift to select multiple items.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the freezing issue with this code. Can you provide a slackblitz ?

Comment: @AkhiAkl https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qojyqc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html. There you go, maybe your list is not big enough to cause it to freeze. I tried with 4000 items, it already freeze for like 5-10 seconds every time you try to destroy the view.

Comment: I think the issue is because of the heavy chunk (4000 records) is removing and inserting back in the DOM. It doesn't cause any problem when toggling `display: none` and `display: block`, since display none doesn't remove it. This even cause problems in material select component too while opening and closing the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Material does provide an option for multi select values

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
<mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat- 
option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

For more information go [Here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

Comment: I need to be able to do multiple select using shift + click. Angular material doesn't support that. The default style from HTML is perfect for me.